# How do you share an Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, apk

I am trying to send the files from an Android project so that a friend of mine can open a new Android project in eclipse and mess around with code/run the project from their home machine.  However, I have run into some problems dealing with missing manifest files, and non-matching signatures.

What is the simplest procedure for bundling up an Android project (not an .apk) to send to someone for their use in eclipse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a Archive File export.  It bundles the projects in your workspace into an exported .zip file.  This .zip file can then be import by the other person into eclipse through the Existing Project importer.

To export:

- File > Export > Archive File

To import:

- File > Import > Existing Projects
  into Workspace
- Select the exported .zip file as
  the Selected archive file

Comment: This is more of what I was looking for, although both answers are correct!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Put it on a source control server, like SVN. If you don't have one, you can use something like Google Code ( http://code.google.com ). Eclipse has built-in source control features to update and commit things to source control.

Comment: I was going to mention that I was looking for an answer not-including this option because I wanted something even simpler and faster as I am required to send the data in a .tar file to my professor's online upload interface.  But I appreciate the answer and it is definitely the most proper way of doing things.