# Received Android src from dev, need to make tweaks, how do I load it on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, src

My dev used a Mac to develop the app and gave me a zip folder. I followed these instructions, but couldn't run the app:

[How do you share an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272802/how-do-you-share-an-android-project)

The 2 folders in the zip folder are "_MACOSX" and "XXXX" <-name of the project

Does it have to do with the fact that I'm on a Windows machine?

I know that I've installed all the SDKs and did a simple "Hello World" app so it's not eclipse.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Here are the description to the error: Project 'XXXX' is missing required library: '\Users\newuser\android-sdk-mac_86\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar'

Comment: just delete the _MACOSX folder and try to import it again...

Comment: Have you installed the Android Development Tools (ADT) into Eclipse? If not, [here's how](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#installation_eclipse).

Comment: Thanks for checking, I did. After getting rid of the MACOSX folder, I get this error: 

Project 'XXXX' is missing required library: '\Users\newuser\android-sdk-mac_86\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar'

How do I replace the android-support-v4.jar that's missing?

Comment: ok, I fixed it using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8580061/1181977 but now  have 26 more errors that popped up, FML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unzip to desktop. Zip the XXXX folder alone. Ignore the MACOS one. Then in Eclipse, try File > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace > click on zipped XXXX project folder from wherever you saved it.